# Numpy, how to retrieve sub-array of array (specific indices)?

Tags: numpy

I have an array:

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
array([[1 2 3]
      [4 5 6]
      [7 8 9]])
```

I want to retrieve a list (or 1d-array) of elements of this array by giving a list of their indices, like so:

```
indices = [[0,0], [0,2], [2,0]]

print(arr1[indices])

# result 

[1,6,7]
```

But it does not work, I have been looking for a solution about it for a while, but I only found ways to select per row and/or per column (not per specific indices)

Someone has any idea ?

Cheers

Aymeric

Answer (score 0):

First make `indices` an array instead of a nested list:

```
indices = np.array([[0,0], [0,2], [2,0]])
```

Then, index the first dimension of `arr1` using the first values of `indices`, likewise the second:

```
arr1[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]]
```

It gives `array([1, 3, 7])` (which is correct, your `[1, 6, 7]` example output is probably a typo).